# mySQL: How to find an item with all specific (included) tags, but cannot include other specific (excluded) tags?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a complicated dataset that contains a variety of data, that needs various filters. This database consists of items that can have various tags.

1. A single item can have multiple tags (30+).
2. The input consists of two comma separated strings:

- **Included**: Example: 'Crimson,Violet'.
- **Excluded**: Example: 'Khaki,Teal'.

3. Find all the itemID's that have **all** tags from the included string but **can not** have a tag that is in the excluded string.
4. It is possible that an item has **multiple tags with the same value**. This is because tags have time attached to it.

Example:

```
Included = 'Violet'
Excluded = 'Crimson'
```

Will return all items having a 'Violet' tag but if an item has 'Crimson' tag too it will not be returned.

**Currently I am working with 3 tables to create filter for this problem**

Main table:

| ItemID | Other columns... |
| --- | --- |
| ID_0 | ... |
| ID_1 | ... |
| ID_2 | ... |
| ID_3 | ... |
| ... | ... |

Linking table:

| ItemID | TagID |
| --- | --- |
| ID_0 | TAG_2 |
| ID_1 | TAG_1 |
| ID_1 | TAG_2 |
| ID_2 | TAG_2 |

Tag table:

| TagID | TagName |
| --- | --- |
| TAG_0 | Teal |
| TAG_1 | Violet |
| TAG_2 | Crimson |
| TAG_3 | Khaki |
| TAG_4 | Fuscia |

I have tried the following:

```sql
SET @returnedValuesLength = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@returnedValues) > 0, CHAR_LENGTH(@returnedValues) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(@returnedValues, ',', '')) + 1, 0);


@myIncludedValues = 'Crimson, Violet'
@myExcludedValues = 'Khaki'



SELECT DISTINCT ItemID 
FROM   main_table 
       JOIN linking_table Lt 
         ON main_table.ItemID = Lt.ItemID
       JOIN tag_table Tt 
         ON Lt.TagID = Tt.TagID
WHERE  Find_in_set(TagName, @myIncludedValues) 
       AND NOT Find_in_set(TagName, @myExcludedValues) 
GROUP  BY ItemID 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT TagName) = @returnedValuesLength 
ORDER  BY ItemID;
```

Comment: Variable names used in the where clause do not match the variable names having the input parameters

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT {columns}
FROM {tables}
GROUP BY {columns}
HAVING SUM(FIND_IN_SET(tag, @myIncludedValues))  -- at least one tag from the list
   AND !SUM(FIND_IN_SET(tag, @myExcludedValues)) -- none tags from the list
```

Comment: Yes this is almost what I am looking for. My bad for not describing the problem properly, but is it necessary that the items have all the tags provided. So in my example the item should have both 'Crimson' and 'Violet'.

Comment: @Sander What is precise version of your MySQL server?

Comment: I am using version 8.0.30

Comment: For this version - parse your CSVs in CTEs and use obtained rowsets in JOIN.